# Dropdown list for ruby methods of a package in RubyMine IDE?

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, rubymine

Usually, the dropdown list in IDEs appear by pressing tab after importing the package and typing its names but not in RubyMine. I have Vim emulation on. I opened up the interactive ruby shell `irb` but cannot get the autocompletion working for the methods of a package.

**How does the autocompletion works in RubyMine and how to list the methods of a package such as OAuth?**

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to leave a reason for a downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

The RubyMine autocompletion works mostly by completing names and keywords used throughout the project see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/auto-completing-code.html) for some details on how that works. There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975469/rubymine-code-autocompletion) question that may provide some clarity as to how completion works in RubyMine.

As for the question about listing available methods in a package (in any object, really). You can use the method `.methods` to get an array of methods the object responds to. ***due to the dynamic nature of ruby and the possibility implement `method_missing`, the list may not contain all possible methods***.

here is an example

```
"string".methods
#=> [:include?, :%, :*, :+, :to_c, :count, :unicode_normalize, :unicode_normalize!, :unicode_normalized?, :partition, :unpack, :unpack1, :sum, :next, :casecmp, :casecmp?, :insert, :bytesize, :match, :match?, :succ!, :+@, :-@, :index, :rindex, :<=>, :replace, :clear, :upto, :getbyte, :==, :===, :setbyte, :=~, :scrub, :[], :[]=, :chr, :scrub!, :dump, :byteslice, :upcase, :next!, :empty?, :eql?, :downcase, :capitalize, :swapcase, :upcase!, :downcase!, :capitalize!, :swapcase!, :hex, :oct, :split, :lines, :reverse, :chars, :codepoints, :prepend, :bytes, :concat, :<<, :freeze, :inspect, :intern, :end_with?, :crypt, :ljust, :reverse!, :chop, :scan, :gsub, :ord, :start_with?, :length, :size, :rstrip, :succ, :center, :sub, :chomp!, :sub!, :chomp, :rjust, :lstrip!, :gsub!, :chop!, :strip, :to_str, :to_sym, :rstrip!, :tr, :tr_s, :delete, :to_s, :to_i, :tr_s!, :delete!, :squeeze!, :each_line, :squeeze, :strip!, :each_codepoint, :lstrip, :slice!, :rpartition, :each_byte, :each_char, :to_f, :slice, :ascii_only?, :encoding, :force_encoding, :b, :valid_encoding?, :tr!, :encode, :encode!, :hash, :to_r, :<, :>, :<=, :>=, :between?, :clamp, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :public_send, :remove_instance_variable, :singleton_method, :instance_variable_set, :define_singleton_method, :method, :public_method, :extend, :to_enum, :enum_for, :!~, :respond_to?, :object_id, :send, :display, :nil?, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_defined?, :!, :!=, :__send__, :equal?, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__id__]
```

for a more useful list, you may want to remove methods that are inherited from Object, like so

```
"string".methods - Object.methods
#=>  [:%, :*, :+, :to_c, :count, :unicode_normalize, :unicode_normalize!, :unicode_normalized?, :partition, :unpack, :unpack1, :sum, :next, :casecmp, :casecmp?, :insert, :bytesize, :match, :match?, :succ!, :+@, :-@, :index, :rindex, :replace, :clear, :upto, :getbyte, :setbyte, :scrub, :[], :[]=, :chr, :scrub!, :dump, :byteslice, :upcase, :next!, :empty?, :downcase, :capitalize, :swapcase, :upcase!, :downcase!, :capitalize!, :swapcase!, :hex, :oct, :split, :lines, :reverse, :chars, :codepoints, :bytes, :concat, :<<, :intern, :end_with?, :crypt, :ljust, :reverse!, :chop, :scan, :gsub, :ord, :start_with?, :length, :size, :rstrip, :succ, :center, :sub, :chomp!, :sub!, :chomp, :rjust, :lstrip!, :gsub!, :chop!, :strip, :to_str, :to_sym, :rstrip!, :tr, :tr_s, :delete, :to_i, :tr_s!, :delete!, :squeeze!, :each_line, :squeeze, :strip!, :each_codepoint, :lstrip, :slice!, :rpartition, :each_byte, :each_char, :to_f, :slice, :ascii_only?, :encoding, :force_encoding, :b, :valid_encoding?, :tr!, :encode, :encode!, :to_r, :between?, :clamp]
```

in your case, you may want to call `OAuth.methods - Object.methods`

more on the `methods` method [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-methods)